# How to get multi-label output after using tf.nn.sigmoid()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

#### Purpose：

I want to get label name directly in tensorflow-serving when prediction, my question is how to transfer `pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(last_layer_output)` to real label name?

#### Question Description：

I know how to do it with multi-classes issue:

```
CLASSES = tf.constant(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

pred = tf.nn.softmax(last_layer_output)

# pred pretty similar to:
pred = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

classes_value = tf.argmax(pred, 1)
classes_name = tf.gather(CLASSES, classes_value)
# classes_name: [b'b' b'd' b'e']
# batch_size = 3
```

So `classes_name` is what I want, I could use it design signature in tensorflow-serving, when I prediction, I could get final labels.

### But how to do like this in multi-label issue?

e.g.

```
CLASSES = tf.constant(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(last_layer_output)
pred = tf.round(pred)

# pred pretty similar to:
pred = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1],     # 'b','c','e'
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],     # 'a','d'
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]     # 'a','b','c','e'
```

How could I transfer `pred` to labels name? I can't do it after `sees.run()` or using other api like `numpy` because this is for tensorflow-serving, I think I need to do it using `tf` method.

Any suggestions are appreciated !

Comment: You can use `tf.where(tf.equal(preds, 1))` to get the indices of `1`s.

Comment: @ManoloSantos then I got my `1` indices array, shape is (9, 2), but how to deal with this tensor? It seems like more complicated

Comment: Even though I got label indices sparse tensor like [[1,2,4],[0,3],[0,1,2,4]], I can't use `tf.gather()` because it needs a dense tensor, so is there any subtle idea or method get multi-labels after using `tf.nn.sigmoid()`?

Comment: @Steven This is multi-label instead of multi-class, so I thought I couldn't use tf.argmax like most tf-Tutourial do, I use  `tf.nn.sigmoid(final _layer_output)` in my model, it means I have more than one target in second dim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first define given probabilities of many classes, which classes you want to return. For example if the probability of this class is above 0.5.

Then you can use `tf.where` with proper condition to get indices and then same `tf.gather` to get classes.

Like this:

```
indicies = tf.where(tf.greater(pred, 0.5))
classes = tf.gather(CLASSES, indicies[:, 1])
```

Then you need to re-organize it using `indicies[:, 0]` that tells you which example the class from.

Also, you must understand that correct form of the answer is SparseTensor, which are not very supported by serving and etc. So you may want to return two tensors [strings and indicators which strings are for which example] and deal with on your client side.

Comment: Thank you man! It seems like useful!, I will try it out then comment! You really saved my ass, Thank u !